# CSS: problem with horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have the following issue whith this very simple task.

I want to create a page with a black footer. Everything in the page should be inside a centered box of 910px of width... EXCEPT THE FOOTER, this should span all over the browser window. The contents of the footer should also be centered and inside a box of 910px of width.

The problem is that when browser window is less than 910px of width, the browser makes some part of the footer magically disappear. I don't know why this happens. I add the complete code and some images illustrating the problem. Thanks in advance :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>prueba pie</title>

    <meta content="es-mx" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pie.css"/>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.registerObject("intro", "9", "expressInstall.swf")
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="secondary">
            <p> ******************************</p>
        </div>

        <div id=footer>
        </div>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(layout.css);

a:link {color:#9A9A9A;}    
a:hover {color:#2A2A2A;} 
a:active {color:#2A2A2A;} 
a:visited{color:#9A9A9A;}

body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: small;
    color: #4B4B4B;
}
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #232323;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FCFCFC;
}
/*---------------- contenedor principal ---------------- */
.main{

    background: #FCFCFC;
    text-align: center;
}

/*---------------- contenedor secundario ---------------- */
.secondary{
    width: 910px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;

}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using google chrome. And I am testing in IE8 too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everything but IE6 you can add min-width: 910px to the #footer rule.  For IE6 I'm not sure

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! I'm so glad! You made my day :D  I've been struggling with this for days.

Comment: By the way, do you know any compatibility issues with firefox or opera?

Comment: For IE6, you'll need a workaround. (It treats `width` as `min-width`. Often people will use the underscore hack to make an extra rule like `_width:910px`, or stick the rule in a conditional comment.)

Answer (score 1):

When a browser window is narrower than its content, by default it scrolls to show all of that content. To turn this off, use `overflow-x:hidden` on `body` or a parent element.

Comment: `overflow-x:hidden` almost does the trick! But the problem is really the whitespace not the overflow. I will try a solution using `overflow-x:hidden` and `min-with: 910px`

Answer (score 0):

Trying putting "width:100%" on main -- or at least inspecting "main" to see how wide it is.  I bet it's only 910px wide.

UPDATE: This works fine in JSfiddle, pretty sure the problem must be in pie.css or layout.css!

Comment: I've tried adding "width:100%" on main but nothing happens. And main is always as wide as the browser window

Answer (score 0):

put your footer id in quotes to abide by XHTML specs ...

`<div id=footer>` should be `<div id="footer">`

Comment: Not an answer, really, even if a good point. Better as a comment.